# What evolutionary pressure would make all of humanity black?

Tags: alternate-history

How would humanity keep an African phenotype hair,skin color,bone structure ect what natural disaster or climate will induce changes to make all humanity black?

Comment: Despite being told multiple time, you insist in editing this post in a way that invalidates existing answers. It will stay locked until you learn to comply with our rules.

Answer (score 2):

## Ultraviolet radiation

That's the whole reason humans evolved to have dark skin in the first place—light skin is more vulnerable to folate depletion under exposure to intense ultraviolet light (i.e. sunlight). You can choose from a variety of reasons for humans being exposed to more UV light. A more UV-transparent atmosphere, a hotter Sun, an Earth where all of the continents are near the equator, etc.

Comment: Folate depletion is a result of dark skin, not light skin. The hazard for light skin is skin damage (burning, excess radicals, increase in cancers), dark skin protects against these.

Comment: @GaryWalker This is false, dark skin protects against folate depletion. https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0914628107#body-ref-r29, https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/206909, https://journals.co.za/doi/pdf/10.10520/AJA20785135_9053

Comment: @GaryWalker you are thinking of Vitamin D

Comment: @John - Dumb, I knew better. UV might lead to folate deficiency the link to Vit. D is strong and my brain flipped it.

Comment: Don't forget altitude. Sudanese are darker because they live at a higher altitude and get even more UV. Other populations at high altitude developed darker skin even with different genetic backgrounds.